# How do I resolve and IP Address from a Host Name on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ip, hostname, resolve

I need to resolve an IP address from a hostname in iOS. I know this is trivial using NSHost, however NSHost resolution capability seems to only work on OSX.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please checked out this link may be helped you........ [http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309927273/programmatically-retrieving-ip-address-of-iphone](http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309927273/programmatically-retrieving-ip-address-of-iphone)

Comment: That gets the ip address of the iOS device, nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like this:

```
struct hostent *host_entry = gethostbyname("stackoverflow.com");
char *buff;
buff = inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr *)host_entry->h_addr_list[0]));
```

buff variable now contain an ip address...

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. However syntax like this makes baby kittens cry. Why C people have to make everything so cryptic is beyond me. Seriously, hostent as a structure... would it have killed them to put an additional -ry at the end?

Comment: Actually, this code looks "easy to read" for me and I never thought that it can be "cryptic" for somebody. BTW, when I saw objective C code - it was very crypty for me too, but not fo long ;)

Comment: When using the code above, my app fails to compile with a warning on the line buff = ... "Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type". Any Idea how to fix this?

Comment: For people who want to use this solution, remember to include these two header files:

#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

Comment: `inet_ntoa` [is not IPv6 compatiable.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html). Use `inet_ntop` instead. [This link](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_ntop) said `inet_ntoa` considered to be deprecated.